# Column user0_.id does not exist

Tags: spring, postgresql

The project crashes for one simple reason - it does not see the table (it seems to me), maybe the problem is in the @Table annotation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class User extends BaseEntity<Long> {
public enum Roles {
    ADMIN
}
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;
@Convert(converter = PurshasedProductConverter.class)
private List<PurshasedProduct> purshasedProducts;


private String email;
private String activationCode;

@Convert(converter = AttachmentConverter.class)
private Attachment userAvatar;
public Attachment getUserAvatar() {
    return userAvatar;
}

public void setUserAvatar(Attachment userAvatar) {
    this.userAvatar = userAvatar;
}


@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String password;
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String temporaryPassword;

@Convert(converter = StringArrayConverter.class)
private String[] roles;

private Date lastPasswordReset;

private Date dateCreated;
private Date dateUpdated;
private Date validatyTime;
private Boolean active;}
```

I used to have `@Table (name = "\" user \ "")`, but this created a lot of other problems for me, now as you see in the code, but it doesn't work. Here is the error itself `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column user0_.id does not exist`

some advise adding schema to the table annotation, but this does not help me

Comment: `user` is a reserved keyword. In SQL you have to use double quotes to use it as an identifier, e.g. `select * from "user"`. Most probably your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") fails to do that. I would strongly recommend to find a different name for that table!

Comment: the fact is that with this name the program worked, but as I change the name of the table, all my migrations will get confused

Comment: try ``@Table(name = "`user`")`` or ``@Table(name="\"user\"")``

Comment: If you have changed the name then set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update in your application.properties

Comment: i try @Table(name = "`user`") or @Table(name="\"user\"") and i get Hibernate: select currval('"user"_id_seq')

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem and including schema name in my @Table annotation solved the problem:

```
@Table(name = "user", schema="mySchema")
```